# How to copy an existing nested array into a new array in state

Tags: arrays, react-native, nested

I am receiving a value from a previous screen that I want to use to retrieve a nested array from another file and set the nested array as a new array in state. So for example in the code below I am receiving the value of "Monday" and would like to set dayValues to {value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3}.

```
const days = [
    {
        Monday: {
            value1: 1,
            value2: 2,
            value3: 3
        },
        Tuesday: {
            value4: 4,
            value5: 5,
            value6: 6
        }
    }
]

const [ dayValues, setDayValues ] = useState({});
```

I understand how to use map to return individual values but haven't been able to find a way to create an entirely new array. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `[value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3]` doesn't make sense in javascript, either it's an object `{value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3}` or an array of objects `[{ value1: 1 }, {value2: 2}, {value3: 3}]`.

Comment: @Abe I am looking for it as an object, so {value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3} .  I'll update my original post to correct it.

Comment: Are you looking for `setDayValues(days[0].Monday)`?

Comment: I think I am. I didn't think it would be that simple! Is it possible to make the .Monday portion receive a variable that changes instead of being fixed? For example, if the variable  being received is const day = Tuesday instead of Monday can it be updated for this? I tried a few variations such as setDayValues(days[0].day) but that didn't work.  Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm still learning RN.

Comment: Sure, you can use square brackets to access the property: `const day = 'Tuesday'; days[0][day]`. You may find RN more accessible if you spend some time on Javascript fundamentals. A lot of RN guides will assume you have a decent foundation in JS.